# Wrong syntax of condition in when using kotlin

Tags: kotlin, range

this is a syntax error

```
 in "C","c".."Z","z"->{//erorr:ClosedRange
        print("Last")
    }
```

but this works ,why ?

```
in "C".."Z","z"->{
        print("Last")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The second version works because you can list multiple conditions that will all run the same branch of code. `in "C".."Z"` is a condition for the value being in a range, while `"z"` is a condition for the value being exactly `"z"`.

You can also do what you were looking for, if you list the two range conditions separately:

```
when(x) {
    in "C".."Z", in "c".."z" -> {
        /* Runs when value is in either range */
    }
    2, 4, 9 -> { 
        /* Another example of multiple conditions for the same 
           branch (only one has to match, of course) */
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to make things more complicated (this is not an answer of course), 
if you run the following code:

```
val c = "California"

when (c) {
    in "A".."z"-> {
        print("Yes")
    }
    else -> {
        print("No")
    }
}
```

what do you think will be printed? `Yes`
because `"A"<"California"<"z"`

So be very careful with string ranges.

Answer (score 0):

This just makes zsmb13's answer more explicit, but doesn't fit well into a comment.

In your first version the compiler sees 3 conditions: `in "C"`, `"c".."Z"`, and `"z"`. The first is valid e.g. for `String`, because it calls the `String.contains(String)` method. The second checks whether the argument of `when` is *equal* to the range `"c".."Z"`, and the third whether it's equal to the string `"z"`.

So if the compiler can tell the argument isn't a `ClosedRange` (because a `String` can't be a `ClosedRange`), then it can't be equal to `"c".."Z"` and the condition can't succeed.